# Saved values to DB are not correct

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, floating-point

Hi I have simple problem. I just multiply two numbers:

```
143.778 * 17 = 2444.226
```

When I'll make object:

```
$row = $this->createRow();
$row->price = 143.778 * 17;
```

it is ok, but when I will save that, by

```
$row->save();
```

in database will store **2444.226074**. It is some known error with float point in mysql or where will appear "074" on the end of float number?

Comment: You should use the exact data types for prices like DECIMAL and let MySQL do the calculation. Errors by using floats are an issue of floats that you can't get rid of.

Comment: I have data type FLOAT 14,6 ... so I will expect 2444.226000. So You think make it DECIMAL 14,6 to obtain correct number? Write answer please ... it is correct and you were first:).

Comment: Just accept one of the existing answers. Best the answer you think it's best. It's not the policy of StackOverflow to encourage the fastest one. And I didn't want to answer really, only to give a hint.

Comment: Ok, I wanted accept your question. Thank you for hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be a float point error because floats are unfortunately approximations of decimal numbers. It is a common mistake to treat them as precise numbers. Float point imprecision becomes more and more apparent as more arithmetical operations are used on the float (recyling the result into an equation(s)). You should never compare float values directly.

Here is some more information about this from MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Try to use a DECIMAL column which is what they recommend to do.

> The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data. In MySQL, NUMERIC is implemented as DECIMAL, so the following remarks about DECIMAL apply equally to NUMERIC.
>
> As of MySQL 5.0.3, DECIMAL values are stored in binary format. Previously, they were stored as strings, with one character used for each digit of the value, the decimal point (if the scale is greater than 0), and the “-” sign (for negative numbers). See Section 12.17, “Precision Math”.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use DECIMAL instead of Float data type change your column

```
ALTER TABLE a MODIFY price DECIMAL(11,6);
```

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766519/mysql-floating-point-rounding-error), 
[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405158/float-value-stored-in-mysql-keeps-getting-messed-up)